# Magento Add filter by subcategory in tool bar

Tags: magento, custom-controls, product

I'm trying to filter products listing with subcategory, Lets say i'm having a top level category named `perfume` and to subcategory named `for him` & `for her`. In top level category listing page i'm trying to include option named `filter results` it should show a dropdown as `for men and for women`

If user clicks `for men` it should show only products in `for men category`

To do this i tried with,

```
<?php $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
         ->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
         ->addAttributeToSelect('my_attribute')
         ->addAttributeToSelect('position')
         ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC')
         ->setLoadProductCount(true)
         ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active',array('eq'=>true))
         ->load(); ?><?php foreach($categories as $key=>$category): ?><?php if($category->getName() != ''):?>    <?php $prodCollection = age::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($category); // Magento product collection ?>
<a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a> (<?php echo $prodCollection->count() ?>)<br/>
```

But it's showing all categories with product counts.
Did anyone know how to filter this to display subcategories only to current main category?

Thanks,.

Comment: Where exactly did you insert this code?

Comment: I inserted this code under my themes view.phtml file....

Comment: can you provide full path please? there are several view.phtml's in Magento.

Comment: Hi tim, I added those codes under frontend/My-Theme/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml Actually i'm trying to filter product lists by subcategories same like http://markavip.com/campaigns/1207drd.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    $rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($rootCategoryId);

?>
<?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a><br/>
<?php endforeach ?>
```